# Get icon index by its resource ID from my executable with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, icons

I am trying to create a shortcut to my GUI app in C++, compiled with Visual Studio. I'm using [IShellLink::SetIconLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to create the link that takes icon index. But the question is how do I get this index when all I have is my icon ID from .res file?

```
#define IDR_ICON_CLEAR                  130
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the negative value of the resource ID, ie -130. Take a look at this  [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100505-00/?p=14153) that explains how you can get the icon by its resource ID.

> In Windows 95, the Extract­Icon function was enhanced so that you could also specify an icon by its resource ID by passing its negative as the icon index. In other words, if you place a negative number after the comma, then its absolute value is interpreted as the resource ID.

Comment: I'm sorry, but use it where? The article you quoted refers to ExtractIcon but I'm not entirely sure how I'd get resourceID-IconIndex association from it?

Comment: IShellLink::SetIconLocation("myapp.exe", -130); or IShellLink::SetIconLocation("myapp.exe", -1 * (IDR_ICON_CLEAR));

Comment: Thanks!
terrible Microsoft